# Workspace settings

Tags: 18.04, workspaces

When I reinstalled 18.04 recently I changed the settings to have the workspace only operate on the primary monitor. I do like this behaviour. But I just went to check to see what other settings were available and for the life of me I am unable to find ANY workspace settings anywhere.

Where are the workspace settings now located?

[image: main settings]
[image: device settings]

Comment: Have you installed gnome tweaks? You can find there.

Comment: oh yes, my bad. I had thought I didn't install any additional tools as I was trying to keep this system as clean as possible. I had in fact installed that. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

as pointed out by PRATAP, it's available in the gnome tweaks tool which I had forgotten I'd installed.

[image]

Comment: This tool should have been included by default!

Comment: To install it...
`sudo add-apt-repository universe; sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool; gnome-tweaks`

Comment: Is there a way to organize the spaces *non-vertically* ?

Answer (score 0):

I have gnome-flashback, gnome-session-flashback, and compiz (including compizconfig-settings-manager) installed on my 18.04 system.  When I use Compiz this setting can be found instead under Applications->System Tools->Preferences->CompizConfig Settings Manager->General Options->Desktop Size.  Changing the "Preferences" settings from the desktop switcher has no effect, and there is no "Workspaces" entry down the left hand side in gnome-tweak-tool.